# Showing $\min\{a+b,c\}\le \min\{b,a+c\}+\min\{a,b+c\}$ for $a,b,c>0$.

Tags: inequality

When I write a proof, I find that the following inequality may hold for $a,b,c>0$:
$$
\min\{a+b,c\}\le \min\{b,a+c\}+\min\{a,b+c\}.
$$
I have tested it with some values of $a,b,c$ and it seems to be true, but I do not know how to prove it.

I tried to prove it using a classified discussion, but I couldn't find a suitable classification.

Comment: Instead, show $$\min\{a+b, c\} \leq \min\{a,c\} + \min\{b,c\}.$$
and then conclude via $\min\{a,c\} \leq \min\{a, b+c\}$ and $\min\{b,c\} \leq \min\{b,a+c\}$.

Comment: @BrianMoehring  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Show that $\min\{a+b, c\} \leq \min\{a, b+c\} + \min\{b, a+c\}$.

---

**Case 1.** $(a, b, c)$ makes a triangle.

$\min\{a+b, c\} = c, \min\{a, b+c\} = a, \min\{b, a+c\}=b.$

$(c) < (a) + (b). \blacksquare$

---

**Case 2.** $c\geq a+b.$

$\min\{a+b, c\} = a+b, \min\{a, b+c\}=a, \min\{b, a+c\}=b.$

$(a+b) = (a) + (b). \blacksquare$

---

**Case 3.** $a \geq b+c.$

$\min\{a+b, c\} = c, \min\{a, b+c\}=b+c, \min\{b, a+c\} = b.$

$(c) < (b+c)+(b). \blacksquare$

---

Q.E.D. (Equality fits when $c \geq a+b.$)